# Retrieving an Attribute Value from an XNode

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have my XML file loaded and then I select my last element. Here is the code:

```
  XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("something.xml");
  var last = doc.Root.LastNode;
```

The code above outputs the last element on the XML file. Here is the code:

```
  <link num="4" url="yahoo.com">Yahoo</link>
```

I want to be able to select the value `4` of `num`. Here is the code:

```
  num="4"
```

How can I select the number 4 from my last node?

Comment: You would retrieve the value from the last node the same way you would from _any_ node. The fact that you want the value from the last node is not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string num = xDoc.Root.Elements().Last().Attribute("num").Value;
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Make sure you have added the following using:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get value with following code.

```
var numValue = ((XElement)last).Attributes("num").FirstOrDefault().Value
```

Comment: `.Value` is not allowed and XElement was not declared

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault().Value` is not allowed

Comment: `((XElement)last).Attributes("num")` outputs `System.Xml.Linq.XElement+<GetAttributes>d_0`